# Basic permission in Bugzilla to separate clients

Tags: mysql, perl, permissions, bugzilla, bug-tracking

I'm trying to configure a Bugzilla instance, which will allow my clients to login, and file bugs for their website under development/maintenance.

For e.g: I have created 2 products called "TestProject", "TestProject2" and a user called "TestClient". What I'm trying to achieve is when TestClient logs in, he can only see TestProject, TestProject2 and only add/modify bugs in there.

TestProject, TestProject2 should not be listed for any other client.

I believe this has do with granular controls in the 'Groups' administration section, however I'm unable to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Where's the Perl? Are you talking about an off-the-shelf software here, if yes, what's its name?

Comment: Yeah, what's the software you're talking about? If it's a programm named "Bugtracker", please provide a link.

Comment: Did some serious goof up! I was referring to Bugzilla, I saw pekka's comment and realized!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.  This is the process I use and it works well for me.

Create a group for each of you clients.
Create or edit the product the client will use.
On the edit products page click "Edit Group Access Controls" 
Select the following for the Group you want to have access
Enable entry, member control = mandatory, other control = mandatory, enable can edit.
Create a user and add them as a member of the new group.

To use this method all bugs have to be associated with a group like this or the users would see their bugs and any non group specific tickets.