# How to restrict group visibility rights inside a product in bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

Like the person in ["separate clients question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102850/basic-permission-in-bugzilla-to-separate-clients) I am trying to define "clients" groups within our bugzilla instance. The difference is in the visibility within a particular product. We would like to:

- have each group of client only see its project and not the other projects (this is the requirement already answered by the question above),
- have the possibility for each project to have bugs filled either by internal people or by the clients,
- bugs filled by clients are seen by other clients (of the same group of course) and by internals,
- *by default* bugs filled by internals are also seen by the client group and by internals, but it is possible for the internal accounts to check a box restricting the visibility to only internal.

I tried to google/groups this but the requirements seem a bit unusual. Also I am confident that it should be possible with the MemberControl/OtherControl options [explained here](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.4/en/html/products.html#product-group-controls). But I can't figure them out. The options I tried were either two restrictive (Mandatory/Mandatory) or not enough (Default/NA for the internal group but then the bug became public, hence the other client groups could see it).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cheers,
Christophe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Bugzilla authorization model is little different. If you want some group to view only one product, on the "Edit group access controls" make him mandatory/mandatory. And only him. And mark the checks to let them edit. Leave all other groups unchecked and NA/NA. Even the administradors. If you have other groups that need access to that product, let`s say the programmers for instance, you have to make their group part of the customer group. Edit the group and mark the programmers group on the "Groups That are members of this group". And so on. 
The idea is: if a product is restricted, then it has to belong to group x. Then add all the additional groups that need access under this master group. The customer group is the master on their products.

Got the idea?